# What is required to fly privately from a region with high levels of the ebola virus (Nigeria) to the UK?

Tags: safety, flight-planning, easa-regulations, uk

My dad will be flying us in a private aircraft from Nigeria back to the UK.

I know that he has been in touch with someone from the UK about this, but since I wasn't present for the conversation I'm not sure what was discussed.

What precautions and declarations should a pilot make when coming from a heavily infected area? We will be landing at a private airport so the current screenings done by major airports will not be considered.

Comment: Avoid transmission vectors (http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs103/en/)

Comment: Nigeria is not "heavily infected": in the current outbreak, only 20 people have been infected, and there have been no new cases since September 8.

Comment: Its still quite an affected area.

Comment: Although the premise of this question (that Nigeria has high levels of ebola virus) is false, the more generic version of the question, along the lines of "What precautions need to be made when flying from an area suffering from an epidemic disease to an area that is not suffering from that disease?", is a good one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll be on a flight plan. You'll have to clear customs at a designated airport and file the appropriate paperwork. More info here:

[Notification of Flights](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/general-aviation-operators-and-pilots-notification-of-flights)

If you notify the border agency it will make recommendations if they think your flight poses a risk. There is only screening at Gatwick and Heathrow.

[Ebola Specific Information](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/public-health-england-enhanced-ebola-screening-process)